# Athena date_parse for date with optional millisecond field

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have date in S3 using which I created an Athena table. I have some date entries in S3 in json format which Athena is not accepting as either Date or timestamp when am running the queries.

Using AWS Athena which uses Prestodb as query engine

Example json :

```
    {"creationdate":"2018-09-12T15:49:07.269Z", "otherfield":"value1"}
    {"creationdate":"2018-09-12T15:49:07Z", "otherfield":"value2"}
```

AWS Glue is taking both the fields as string and when am changing them to timestamp and date respectively the queries around timestamp are not working giving ValidationError on the timestamp field.

Anyway, I found a way to use prestodb date_parse function but its not working either since some fields have milliseconds while other not.

```
    parse_datetime(creationdate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
    parse_datetime(creationdate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')
```

Both are failing because of different entries present i.e. one with millisecond %f and one without
Is there a way to provide a parser, regex so that am able to convert these strings into Date during sql query execution?

Answer (score 17):

Instead of providing the timestamp format, you can use the `from_iso8601_timestamp` function.

This way, all timestamps get parsed.

```
select from_iso8601_timestamp(creationdate) from table1;
```

Comment: Awesome Jens, it worked in all cases. Thanks.
+1 for your solution

Comment: @jens walter : saved a lot of time and effort /\

Answer (score -3):

Do you just need date?

If so you could use date_parse(string, format).

```
date_parse(creationdate, ‘%Y-%m-%d’)
```

Comment: no need to do time_diff and hence millisecond parsing was important.

Answer (score -3):

Use this:

```
SELECT requestdatetime, remoteip, requester, key
       FROM MYDB.TABLE
       WHERE parse_datetime(requestdatetime,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z') 
       BETWEEN parse_datetime('2020-10-14:00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss')
           AND parse_datetime('2020-10-14:23:59:59','yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss');
```