# MAX() and date_parse to pull back latest event date in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm trying to run a query in Athena where the latest event date is the only row that gets returned. Initially, I'm first trying to parse the event date from a string (Partitioned) to yyyy/mm/dd. After that, I want to pull ONLY the MAX() or latest event date details.

Here's what I currently have and the error I'm getting

```
select CAST(date_parse(eventdate,'%yyyy/%mm/%dd')AS date)
```

`INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "20221204" is malformed at "221204"`

Comment: Can you provide us with some examples of the input data?

Comment: pl refer to this answer, it could be the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52309683/2067753 if this isn't helpful then we are going to need exactly what data type `eventdate` is, and sample of data from that column.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm first trying to parse the event date from a string (Partitioned) to yyyy/mm/dd

You don't parse TO, you parse FROM and you need to parse providing correct format.

`date_parse` uses [MySQL format specifiers](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions), and your current format does not make much sense compared to the passed date, you need to fix it (both specifiers and delimiter which is not present in date string):

```sql
select CAST(date_parse('20221204', '%Y%m%d') AS date);
```

Output:

```
   _col0
------------
 2022-12-04
```

If you want to format the date after that - then just use [`date_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format) (cast also not needed):

```sql
select date_format(date_parse('20221204', '%Y%m%d'), '%Y/%m/%d');
```

Output:

```
   _col0
------------
 2022/12/04
```